# Rendering sparklines in LaTeX in R Markdown using gtExtras

Tags: r, r-markdown, gt, gtextras

This code from [gtExtras](https://jthomasmock.github.io/gtExtras/reference/gt_plt_dist.html) website:

```
library(gt)
gt_sparkline_tab <- mtcars %>%
    dplyr::group_by(cyl) %>%
    # must end up with list of data for each row in the input dataframe
    dplyr::summarize(mpg_data = list(mpg), .groups = "drop") %>%
    gt() %>%
    gt_plt_dist(mpg_data) %>% as_latex()
gt_sparkline_tab
```

gives the following error when rendering to LaTeX:

> ! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal
> mode. l.355 ... circle {      fill: none;      stroke: #
> 000000;      stroke-lineca...

I can't quite figure how to bypass this.

Comment: Most likely not possible. See [here](https://github.com/jthomasmock/gtExtras/issues/65#issuecomment-1243853960) for a related GitHub issue and the package authors response on Latex support.